# Javascript OOP three.js uniform returns undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

Hey I'm a beginner with `OOP` inside javascript and I'm trying to create a `three.js` scene.

I made a little test setup with uniforms that's value changes with choosing a file.

I'm getting a `"undefined"-error` when trying to change the uniforms' value after the file is selected. I pretty much know the cause of this since I'm defining a object inside the object's function, so **"this"** is not referring to the original Object anymore.

Anyways, I can't come up with a solution for this. Here's the setup:

```
var SCENE = function()
{
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    this.camera.position.z = 500;
    this.scene.add(this.camera);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.mesh);

    this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.uniforms = {
        resolution: { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
    };
}

SCENE.prototype.render = function()
  {
      this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
      this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };

SCENE.prototype.valMethode = function()
  {
    console.log(this.uniforms.resolution.value);
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function()
    {
      this.uniforms.resolution.value = 10.0;
    }
    image.src = "someImage.jpg";
   }

var test = new SCENE();
test.render();
test.valMethode();
```

Comment: refer `var self = this;` outside the scope of SCENE, then proceed to use `self.uniform = {}` ..

Comment: yes, thank you! This works :)